# Partitioning boot sectors after a Windows 10 install

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I apologize for the title of the post, as I am not sure how to phrase it more precisely. Hopefully someone would correct it.

I have an SSD that has Windows 10 on it. I am going to remove completely Windows and install Ubuntu (perhaps another distro beside it, but no Windows). When I come to the partitioning part of the installation I am not sure how to partition the boot partitions. Grub, UEFI, etc. is all foreign to me. As far as I could tell I need to manually create partitions, but how many, what size, what type - that I couldn't find, or the explanation must have been foreign to me.

Comment: You can select "Erase and install" and not worry about partitioning.

Comment: But then would I be able to create the other partitions - i.e. one for Ubuntu and one for files and documents?

Comment: You can later boot a live session, shrink the main partition and create other but alternatively do it during installation. Currently you only need one partition for Ubuntu, thanks to swapfile, and, of course, keep the EFI partition.

Comment: You must have a 'root' ( / ) partition, and maybe a 'swap' partition. Some users prefer to have a separate 'home' partition as well, but I've never found that necessary. Don't create a boot partition. Ubuntu will create one for you.